# How to respond to events for objects in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, events, event-handling, eventhandler

I have made an array of tiles (pictureboxes) in an array and need them to all do something when clicked, but don't know how. Specifically, I want to be able to place some other object on them by clicking a tile and making that object go to that tile's location. I know you may suggest looking at the mouseposition variable and having some invisible box over all the tiles to register clicks, but I would like to know how to register any event for an object in an array for anything that comes up in the future. I do know how to register events for objects which aren't in an array by the way.
The object I want to move on top of the picturebox will also be from an object array, but a different one.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim tiles(50) As PictureBox 'This is the object array of tiles
    Dim plants() As String 'I haven't set this up yet, but this will be for the objects to be 'placed' on the pictureboxes.

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim tileWidth As Integer = 50
        Dim tileHeight As Integer = 50
        Dim xindent As Integer = 10
        Dim yindent As Integer = 10
        For x = 0 To 9
            For y = 0 To 4
                ReDim Preserve tiles(x * y)
                tiles(x * y) = New PictureBox With {.Visible = True, .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 50), .Parent = Me, .BackColor = Color.GreenYellow, .Image = Nothing}
                tiles(x * y).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x * tileWidth + xindent, y * tileHeight + yindent)
                If (x Mod 2 = 0 And y Mod 2 = 0) Or (x Mod 2 <> 0 And y Mod 2 <> 0) Then
                    tiles(x * y).BackColor = Color.Green
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I simply don't know how to set up the click event handler for the array of tiles so that's why its not in the code above.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) is there for that. After the New you just need to attach a function to the event

```
AddHandler tiles(x * y).Click, AddressOf Tile_Click
```

And have a function that handles the event

```
Private Sub Tile_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    ' sender represent the reference to the picture box that was clicked

End Sub
```

If you already know the size of the array, you should ReDim your array just once instead of each time you loop (Move the ReDim out of the loops). Also, since y is 0 on the first loop, you are basically doing a ReDim of 0 elements (x*y = 0 when y = 0)

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot more sense now. However, I'm not really sure what you meant by redimming 0 elements, as I was using the stuff in the brackets as the index of the object to be set up, not the number of objects to be set up.

Comment: @TeeMee123 Look at the first pass in your loop (x = 0, y = 0). When you multiply them together it makes 0 (redim reduce the array length and you are creating a new element at index 0). Now on your second pass (x = 0, y = 1). When you multiply x*y = 0*1 it will also be 0. Same for your second pass (x = 0, y = 2).

Comment: @TeeMee123 When (x = 1, y = 2) it will create a new picture at index 2 (x*y = 1*2 = 2). But you'll then have a problem when (x = 2, y = 1) since multiplying then will result with a 2 (x*y = 2*1 = 2).

Answer (score 0):

the_lotus has already given you a great answer.

Just wanted to share a trick I often use when wiring up events with `AddHandler`.

Declare a temporary variable using `WithEvents` in your class:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents Tile As PictureBox

    ...
```

Now, in the two DropDowns across the top of code editor, change `Form1` to `Tile`, and `(Declarations)` to `Click` (or whatever event you want).  This will enter a method for you that has the correct **method signature**:

```
Private Sub Tile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tile.Click

End Sub
```

Delete the `Handles Tile.Click` portion that appears at the end of the first line:

```
Private Sub Tile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 

End Sub
```

Finally, remove your temporary declaration that used `WithEvents`.

Now you've got a method with the correct signature that you can use with `AddHandler`.  This is very handy for events that don't have the standard signature.